# Swift distance() method throws fatal error: can not increment endIndex

Tags: xcode, swift

I was trying to find a substring match in a string, and get the matched position.

I can't figure out what's wrong with the following code:

```
let str1 = "hello#ﾟДﾟ"
let cmp = "ﾟДﾟ"
let searchRange = Range(start: str1.startIndex, end: str1.endIndex)
let range = str1.rangeOfString(cmp, options: .allZeros, range: searchRange)

println("\(searchRange), \(range!)") // output: 0..<9, 6..<9

let dis = distance(searchRange.startIndex, range!.startIndex) // fatal error: can not increment endIndex! reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
// let dis = distance(searchRange.startIndex, range!.endIndex) // This will go and output: distance=7

println("distance=\(dis)")
```

As the comments suggested, although the `range` had valid values, the distance() method threw a fatal error.

If I'm wrong about the use of distance(), what method should I use to archive the target?
 Any advice would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: In order to work, `distance` needs a start and end range from the same container. You need a find function, but Swift doesn't have one in its library that will do what you want.

Comment: what are you trying to do? get the range of substring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`range!.startIndex` points here:

```
"hello#ﾟДﾟ"
       ^
```

But, in this case, `#ﾟ` is a single character in Swift.

Therefore, This code:

```
for var idx = searchRange.startIndex; idx != range!.startIndex; idx = idx.successor() {
    println("\(idx): \(str1[idx])");
}
```

prints:

```
0: h
1: e
2: l
3: l
4: o
5: #ﾟ
7: Дﾟ
fatal error: Can't form a Character from an empty String
// and emits BAD_INSTRUCTION exception
```

As you can see `range!.startIndex` never matches to the character boundaries, and the `for` loop run out the string. That's why you see the exception.

In theory, since `String` is considered as "Collection of `Character`s" in Swift,  `"ﾟДﾟ"` should not be a substring of  `"hello#ﾟДﾟ"`.

I think `.rangeOfString()` uses `NSString` implementation which treats string as a sequence of `unichar`. I don't know this should be considered as a bug or not.

Comment: You are right, "ﾟ" (HALFWIDTH KATAKANA SEMI-VOICED SOUND MARK) is some kind of combining character and "#ﾟ" is an extended grapheme cluster. Swift.String.rangeOfString() should return nil.

Comment: From your answer, I think I know the point I misunderstood. I was stuck on finding what's wrong with the distance() method, but forgot that there are mismatches between the Swift world and the Cocoa world. So although `rangeOfString` takes Swift parameters, itself comes from the Cocoa and may disobey Swift policy. I agree with you that if there are some bugs, it should be `rangeOfString`. And I think use pure NSString may be a workaround.

Comment: Yes, in this case, you should use `NSString` and `NSRange`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
func search<C: CollectionType where C.Generator.Element: Equatable>(col1: C, col2: C) -> C.Index? {
    if col2.startIndex == col2.endIndex {
        return col1.startIndex
    }

    var col1Ind = col1.startIndex
    while col1Ind != col1.endIndex {
        var ind1 = col1Ind
        var ind2 = col2.startIndex
        while col1[ind1] == col2[ind2] {
            ++ind1; ++ind2
            if ind2 == col2.endIndex { return col1Ind }
            if ind1 == col1.endIndex { return nil }
        }
        ++col1Ind
    }
    return nil
}
```

Searches for the first instance of the col2 sequence in col1. If found, returns the index of the start of the sub-sequence. If not found, returns nil. If col2 is empty, returns the startIndex of col1.