# Conforming String.CharacterView.Index to Strideable: fatal error when using stride(to:by:): "cannot increment endIndex "

Tags: swift

### Question:

When attempting to stride over `String.CharacterView.Index` indices by e.g. a stride of `2`

```
extension String.CharacterView.Index : Strideable { }

let str = "01234"
for _ in str.startIndex.stride(to: str.endIndex, by: 2) { } // fatal error
```

I get the following runtime exception

> fatal error: cannot increment endIndex

Just creating the `StrideTo<String.CharacterView.Index>` above, however, (`let foo = str.startIndex.stride(to: str.endIndex, by: 2)`) does not yield an error, only when attempting to stride/iterate over or operate on it (`.next()`?).

- What is the reason for this runtime exception; is it expected (mis-use of conformance to `Stridable`)?

I'm using **Swift 2.2** and **Xcode 7.3**. Details follow below.

**Edit addition: error source located**

Upon reading my question carefully, it would seem as if the error really does occur in the `next()` method of `StrideToGenerator` (see bottom of this post), specifically at the following marked line

```
let ret = current
current += stride  // <-- here
return ret
```

Even if the last update of `current` will never be returned (in next call to `next()`), the final advance of `current` index to a value larger or equal to that of `_end` yields the specific runtime error above (for `Index` type `String.CharacterView.Index`).

```
(0..<4).startIndex.advancedBy(4) // OK, -> 4
"foo".startIndex.advancedBy(4)   // fatal error: cannot increment endIndex
```

However, one question still remains:

- Is this a bug in the `next()` method of `StrideToGenerator`, or just an error that pops up due to a mis-use of `String.CharacterView.Index` conformance to `Stridable`?

---

### Related

The following Q&A is related to *the subject of a iterating over characters in steps other than `+1`*, and worth including in this question even if the two questions differ.

- [Using String.CharacterView.Index.successor() in for statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36194060/using-string-characterview-index-successor-in-for-statements/)

Especially note [@Sulthan:s neat solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36207901/4573247) in the thread above.

---

### Details

*(Apologies for hefty details/investigations of my own, just skip these sections if you can answer my question without the details herein)*

The [`String.CharacterView.Index` type](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/String.CharacterView.Index/) describes a character position, and:

- conforms to `Comparable` (and in so, `Equatable`),
- contains implementations for `advancedBy(_:)` and `distanceTo(_:)`.

Hence, it can directly be made to conform to the [protocol `Strideable`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/Strideable/), making use of `Stridable`:s default implementations of methods `stride(through:by:)` and `stride(to:by:)`. The examples below will focus on the latter (analogous problems with the former):

> ...
>
> ```
> func stride(to end: Self, by stride: Self.Stride) -> StrideTo<Self>
> ```
>
> Returns the sequence of values *(self, self + stride, self + stride +
>   stride, ... last)* where last is the last value in the progression
>   **that is less than end**.

**Conforming to `Stridable` and striding by `1`: all good**

Extending `String.CharacterView.Index` to `Stridable` and striding by `1` works fine:

```
extension String.CharacterView.Index : Strideable { }

var str = "0123"

// stride by 1: all good
str.startIndex.stride(to: str.endIndex, by: 1).forEach {
    print($0,str.characters[$0])
} /* 0 0 
     1 1 
     2 2
     3 3 */
```

For an even number of indices in `str` above (indices `0..<4`), this also works for a stride of `2`:

```
// stride by 2: OK for even number of characters in str.
str.startIndex.stride(to: str.endIndex, by: 2).forEach {
    print($0,str.characters[$0])
} /* 0 0
     2 2 */
```

**However, for some cases of striding by `>1`: runtime exception**

For an odd number of indices and a stride of `2`, however, the stride over the character views indices yield a runtime error

```
// stride by 2: fatal error for odd number of characters in str.
str = "01234"
str.startIndex.stride(to: str.endIndex, by: 2).forEach {
    print($0,str.characters[$0])
} /* 0 0
     2 2
     fatal error: cannot increment endIndex */
```

### Investigations of my own

My own investigations into this made me suspect the error comes from the `next()` method of the [`StrideToGenerator` structure](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/StrideToGenerator/), possibly when this method calls `+=` on the stridable element

```
public func += <T : Strideable>(inout lhs: T, rhs: T.Stride) {
  lhs = lhs.advancedBy(rhs)
}
```

(from a version of the Swift source for [`swift/stdlib/public/core/Stride.swift`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/174d475833838fda986120dabc009377ffaa89b6/stdlib/public/core/Stride.swift) that somewhat corresponds to Swift 2.2). Given the following Q&A:s

- [Trim end off of string in swift, getting error at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29277746/trim-end-off-of-string-in-swift-getting-error-at-runtime),
- [Swift distance() method throws fatal error: can not increment endIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191865/swift-distance-method-throws-fatal-error-can-not-increment-endindex),

we could suspect that we would possibly need to use `String.CharacterView.Index.advancedBy(_:limit:)` rather than `...advancedBy(_:)` above. <strike>However from what I can see, the `next()` method in `StrideToGenerator` guards against advancing the index past the limit.</strike>

**Edit addition:** the source of the error seems to indeed be located in the `next()` method in `StrideToGenerator`:

```
// ... in StrideToGenerator
public mutating func next() -> Element? {
    if stride > 0 ? current >= end : current <= end {
        return nil
    }
    let ret = current
    current += stride /* <-- will increase current to larger or equal to end 
                               if stride is large enough (even if this last current
                               will never be returned in next call to next()) */
    return ret
}
```

Even if the last update of `current` will never be returned (in next call to `next()`), the final advance of `current` index to a value larger or equal to that of `end` yields the specific runtime error above, for `Index` type `String.CharacterView.Index`.

```
(0..<4).startIndex.advancedBy(4) // OK, -> 4
"foo".startIndex.advancedBy(4)   // fatal error: cannot increment endIndex
```

Is this to be considered a bug, or is `String.CharacterView.Index` simply not intended to be (directly) conformed to `Stridable`?

Comment: Note fun workaround to the whole issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36207901/341994

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply declaring the protocol conformance

```
extension String.CharacterView.Index : Strideable { }
```

compiles because `String.CharacterView.Index` conforms to 
`BidirectionalIndexType` , and `ForwardIndexType/BidirectionalIndexType` have default method implementations for `advancedBy()` and `distanceTo()`
as required by `Strideable`.

`Strideable` has the default protocol method implementation
for `stride()`:

```
extension Strideable {
    // ...
    public func stride(to end: Self, by stride: Self.Stride) -> StrideTo<Self>
}
```

So the only methods which are "directly" implemented for
`String.CharacterView.Index` are – as far as I can see - the `successor()` and `predecessor()` methods from `BidirectionalIndexType`.

As you already figured out, the default method implementation of
`stride()` does not work well with `String.CharacterView.Index`.

<strike>But is is always possible to define dedicated methods for a concrete type.</strike> For the **problems** of making `String.CharacterView.Index` conform to `Strideable` see 
[Vatsal Manot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36206399/1187415) below and the discussion in the comments – it took me a while to get what he meant :)

Here is a possible implementation of a `stride(to:by:)` method for `String.CharacterView.Index`:

```
extension String.CharacterView.Index {
    typealias Index = String.CharacterView.Index

    func stride(to end: Index, by stride: Int) -> AnySequence<Index> {

        precondition(stride != 0, "stride size must not be zero")

        return AnySequence { () -> AnyGenerator<Index> in
            var current = self
            return AnyGenerator {
                if stride > 0 ? current >= end : current <= end {
                    return nil
                }
                defer {
                    current = current.advancedBy(stride, limit: end)
                }
                return current
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work as expected:

```
let str = "01234"
str.startIndex.stride(to: str.endIndex, by: 2).forEach {
    print($0,str.characters[$0])
}
```

Output

```
0 0
2 2
4 4
```

Answer (score 2):

To simply answer your ending question: this is not a bug. This is normal behavior.

`String.CharacterView.Index` can never exceed the `endIndex` of the parent construct (i.e. the character view), and thus triggers a runtime error when forced to (as correctly noted in the latter part of your answer). This is by design.

The only solution is to write your own alternative to the `stride(to:by:)`, one that avoids equalling or exceeding the `endIndex` in any way.

As you know already, you can technically implement `Strideable`, but you *cannot* prevent that error. And since `stride(to:by:)` is not blueprinted within the protocol itself but introduced in an extension, there is no way you can use a "custom" `stride(to:by:)` in a generic scope (i.e. `<T: Strideable>` etc.). Which means you should probably not try and implement it unless you are absolutely sure that there is no way that error can occur; something which seems impossible.

**Solution:** There isn't one, currently. However, if you feel that this is an issue, I encourage you to start a thread in the [swift-evolution mailing list](https://lists.swift.org/mailman/listinfo/swift-evolution), where this topic would be best received.

Comment: @VatsalManot: I am not sure if I understand what you mean. You can define a `extension String.CharacterView.Index : Strideable` with a `strideTo` method. Perhaps I am overlooking something?

Comment: @MartinR: Yes, I believe you are. The runtime error _cannot be avoided_. `stride(to:by:)` is implemented in an extension, not declared in the protocol. So if working with a generic `Strideable`, the compiler will always choose the default implementation over the custom one.

Comment: @MartinR: The problem lies not in the `strideTo` function, but in `stride(to:by)`, where `next()` called on an index with value `endIndex - 1` triggers a runtime error. An unavoidable error, by design.

Comment: @MartinR: `extension String.CharacterView.Index: Strideable {}` with a custom `stride(to:by:)` implementation is not a correct solution, for the reasons I just pointed out. However, the `stride(to:by:)` on it's own will not cause any issues.

Comment: @VatsalManot: *"... the compiler will always choose the default implementation over the custom one."* – That is not correct. See "Providing Default Implementations" in the Swift book: "If a conforming type provides its own implementation of a required method or property, that implementation will be used instead of the one provided by the extension." – My example is not perfect, but it shows that it can be done.

Comment: @MartinR: You completely missed the "if working with a generic `Strideable`" part.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer; it's just that your question got me playing around. Let's ignore Stridable and just try striding through a character view:

```
    let str = "01234"
    var i = str.startIndex
    // i = i.advancedBy(1)
    let inc = 2
    while true {
        print(str.characters[i])
        if i.distanceTo(str.endIndex) > inc {
            i = i.advancedBy(inc)
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
```

As you can see, it is crucial to test with `distanceTo` *before* we call `advancedBy`. Otherwise, we risk attempting to advance right through the end index and we'll get the "fatal error: can not increment endIndex" bomb.

So my thought is that something like this must be necessary in order to make the indices of a character view stridable.

Comment: Thanks! I realized the same upon reading my own question: the default implementation of the `stride` functions make use (via `Stridable` types `+=` operator) of the non-bounds-checking `advancedBy(_:)`, which in combination with the non-thorough bounds testing in `StrideToIterator .next()` will fail the crucial test you've performed above.